# Trusting SSL Certificates

Tags: objective-c, ios, ssl

I cant get this SSL-thing to work:
I downloaded the cert from the server, which works perfectly.
I also added the myCertificate.cert to my iPhone-Keychain using the code in this thread: [Importing an SSL cert under the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746005/importing-an-ssl-cert-under-the-iphone-sdk)
But still the NSURLConnection (async) gives me a kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure.
Can anyone help an tell me what I'm doing wrong? It's the second full day of search now and I'm becoming desperate...

Comment: Have you found this post yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340937/continuously-getting-ksectrustresultrecoverabletrustfailure-while-trust-evaluati

Comment: No, I hadn't. I now figured out that I get a 'kSecTrustResultUnspecified'... Seems to me that there's something missing in my keachain maybe?!

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8937798/703809) helped me when I had similar problem. Make sure your certificate contains the extensions.